# jquery if checked all sum x2

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, sum

I have some problem with sum

example:
if checkbox with `id='sms'` is checked total sum x2 else x1

```
<form>
<input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="1.00"> $1.00<br>
<input onclick="clickCh(this)" type="checkbox" value="2.00"> $2.00<br>
<input id="sms" type="checkbox"> pay via sms<br>
     <BR>
<input id="total" type="text" name="total">
</form>
</div>

<script>
var total = document.getElementById("total")

$('#sms').change(function(){
    var rise = this.checked ? '2' : '1';
});

 function clickCh(caller){
  if(caller.checked){
   add(caller)
  } else {
   subtract(caller)
  }
 }
function add(caller){ 
    total.value = total.value*1 + caller.value*1 * rise
        }
function subtract(caller){ 
    total.value = total.value*1 - caller.value*1 * rise
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`rise`'s scope is only within this function:

```
$('#sms').change(function(){
    var rise = this.checked ? '2' : '1';
});
```

Declare it outside then modify it:

```
var rise;

$('#sms').change(function(){
    rise = this.checked ? 2 : 1;
});
```

Comment: ok this work , but when i uncheck checkbox , total value don't empty :(

Comment: Do you change the value when the checkbox changes state?